# What is the build number of Delphi2009 after the fourth service pack?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, servicepacks

I installed Delphi 2009 Update 4 yesterday (very painful process ;)

Now, How can I make sure if it is properly updated?

What is the build number shown in the IDE about box?

Answer (score 3):

The latest Update for Delphi 2009 was "Update 3", which sets the version number to 12.0.3420.21218

"Update 4" is a "database pack" update, it doesn't change Delphi's version number.

Answer (score 2):

I have update 4 applied and my version number is:
 Version 12.0.3420.21218